# React JS, unable to update Redux state using dispatch hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

My react code contain input field,if I enters text in input field,the redux state updates and displays result in same component but I gets error with my dispatch function. My dispatch function unable to connect with the proper action function.

Please verify my Code

I have copied the code to CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-currying-hjwur?file=/src/App.js

- The useSelector() hook work fine for me,ie I am able to access the redux store *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing `loginUser` into rootActions.js and renaming it to `loginActions`, hence the confusion.

changing line 10 of Header.js to

`dispatch(rootActions.loginAction(user_name));`

will make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with this call `dispatch(rootAction.loginAction.loginUser(userName))` while rootAction has loginAction but loginAction is a function not an object with loginUser as it is default export.

Change it to `dispatch(rootAction.loginAction(user_name));` and it should work.